# Displying local HTML inside iframe, Angular-8

Tags: angular

I wan to display local HTML file in Angular8, but it is not displaying that file. Please see [slack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt6ry6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Please help.

Comment: any reason why you need to use a local file in a iframe ?

Comment: we have some prerendered HTML, just to show

Comment: why not just display it as a angular component ?

Comment: its complicated , using various libraries

Answer (score 5):

Try to put your file bb.html inside assets folder and to your component ts just set the url:

```
url = './assets/bb.html';
```

then set the safe pipe you have on your slack to the iframe src:

```
<iframe #iframe width="200" height="200" src="url | safe"></iframe>
```